# netutils Java networking library not working

Tags: java

I found a networking library for java named netutils.
[This is the homepage](https://code.google.com/p/netutils/).

I need to edit tcp packets.

The library jnetpcap has too many bugs so I'm trying to find another library. This netutils seems to be really good, but in the manual it says to have the libnet.lib
and netutils.dll files.

I'm having trouble locating the correct files.

Comment: Please actually use capital letters to make your question easier to read. I have fixed this for you, but please do this next time.

Comment: Have you installed winpcap?

Comment: Yes i did, Not seems to work..